# Cube Generation Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, three.js, 3d

I have a randomly generated array of cubes, each one has its position and color. That cubes are placed on a field, the field size is 5x5. Each cube is connected with at least one another cube. I need to add a "floating cube feature". That means that I need to randomly add a cube that doesn't have anything below/above it but is connected with another cube by one side ( see the image)[image: source]
What I need to add: [image: Expected result]
Array of cubes on the image:

```
var cube_arr = [{posX: -2, posY: 0, posZ: 1, color: "red", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 1, posZ: 1, color: "red", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 2, posZ: 1, color: "green", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 3, posZ: 1, color: "purple", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 0, posZ: 0, color: "blue", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 1, posZ: 0, color: "blue", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 2, posZ: 0, color: "blue", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 3, posZ: 0, color: "green", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 0, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 1, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 2, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 3, posZ: -1, color: "purple", row: 1},
{posX: -1, posY: 0, posZ: 2, color: "green", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 1, posZ: 2, color: "purple", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 0, posZ: 1, color: "black", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 1, posZ: 1, color: "red", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 0, posZ: 0, color: "black", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 1, posZ: 0, color: "black", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 2, posZ: 0, color: "green", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 0, posZ: -1, color: "blue", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 1, posZ: -1, color: "blue", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 2, posZ: -1, color: "green", row: 2},
{posX: 0, posY: 0, posZ: 1, color: "red", row: 3},
{posX: 0, posY: 0, posZ: 0, color: "black", row: 3},
{posX: 0, posY: 1, posZ: 0, color: "red", row: 3},
{posX: 0, posY: 0, posZ: -1, color: "blue", row: 3},
{posX: 0, posY: 1, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 3},
{posX: 1, posY: 0, posZ: 1, color: "red", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 1, posZ: 1, color: "purple", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 0, posZ: 0, color: "black", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 1, posZ: 0, color: "blue", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 0, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 1, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 2, posZ: -1, color: "purple", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 3, posZ: -1, color: "yellow", row: 4},
{posX: 2, posY: 0, posZ: 0, color: "green", row: 5},
{posX: 2, posY: 1, posZ: 0, color: "green", row: 5},
{posX: 2, posY: 2, posZ: 0, color: "yellow", row: 5}]
```

Comment: aaaaand where is your code?

Comment: My code generates this array. So basically I have an array of 38 cubes.

Comment: @Berto99 added!

Comment: why not use `5x5x5` 3D array for the map where array index is the cube position (instead of 1D)? that would ease up the search a lot ...

Comment: Seems like you need to write 2 functions:  The first to check if a field position is empty.  The second function to loop through all the possible field positions, using the first function to check if above and below are empty, and if so then check all 4 sides to determine if only one side cell is not empty.  With this list of available field positions to fill, randomly pick one and fill it...

Answer (score 0):

This should work (it's hard to try without making proper testing, which in this case is hard to do without the code to visualize it).

`randomFloatingCube` receives the array of cubes and also the min and max value `posX` and `posZ` can take, so the floating cube doesn't end up being generated outside the scope.

You may notice at the end of `randomFloatingCube` I am returning a single random cube, but if you return the array `floatingCubes` instead you should have all possible floating cubes there.

Please let me know if it worked for you.

```js
// Returns a floating cube within the x0-x1, z0-z1 square
function randomFloatingCube(A, x0, x1, z0, z1){

  let floatingCubes = [];
  
  // make a copy of the array sorted by posY
  // and exclude cubes from the first level (posy == 0)
  const B = A.sort((a, b) => b.posY - a.posY ).filter((b) => b.posY > 0);
  
  // loop trough cubes from bigger to lower posY
  for(let i=0; i<B.length; i++){
    const a = B[i];
    
    let adjacent = getAdjacentCubes(a.posY, a.posX, a.posZ);
    
    let candidates = adjacent.filter((c) => {
    
      if(c.posX < x0 && c.posX > x1 && c.posZ < z0 && c.posZ > z1){
        return false;
      }
      for(let j=0; j<A.length; j++){
        const b = A[j];
        
        if(b.posY >= c.posY - 1 && b.posY <= c.posY + 1 && c.posX == b.posX && c.posZ == b.posZ){
          // exclude candidates with top or bottom adjacent
          return false;
          break;
        } else if(b.posY == c.posY && b.posZ == c.posZ && b.posX == c.posX) {
          // exclude adjacent cubes already present in the array
          return false;
          break;
        }
      }
      
      return true;
      
    });
    
    floatingCubes.push(...candidates);
  }

  return floatingCubes[ Math.round(Math.random() * (floatingCubes.length - 1)) ];
}

function getAdjacentCubes(posY, posX, posZ){
  let ret = [];
  
  [posX-1, posX+1].forEach((x)=>{
    ret.push({
      posY,
      posX: x,
      posZ
    });
  });
  [posZ-1, posZ+1].forEach((z)=>{
    ret.push({
      posY,
      posX,
      posZ: z
    });
  });

  return ret;
}

var cube_arr = [{posX: -2, posY: 0, posZ: 1, color: "red", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 1, posZ: 1, color: "red", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 2, posZ: 1, color: "green", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 3, posZ: 1, color: "purple", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 0, posZ: 0, color: "blue", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 1, posZ: 0, color: "blue", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 2, posZ: 0, color: "blue", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 3, posZ: 0, color: "green", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 0, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 1, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 2, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 1},
{posX: -2, posY: 3, posZ: -1, color: "purple", row: 1},
{posX: -1, posY: 0, posZ: 2, color: "green", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 1, posZ: 2, color: "purple", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 0, posZ: 1, color: "black", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 1, posZ: 1, color: "red", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 0, posZ: 0, color: "black", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 1, posZ: 0, color: "black", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 2, posZ: 0, color: "green", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 0, posZ: -1, color: "blue", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 1, posZ: -1, color: "blue", row: 2},
{posX: -1, posY: 2, posZ: -1, color: "green", row: 2},
{posX: 0, posY: 0, posZ: 1, color: "red", row: 3},
{posX: 0, posY: 0, posZ: 0, color: "black", row: 3},
{posX: 0, posY: 1, posZ: 0, color: "red", row: 3},
{posX: 0, posY: 0, posZ: -1, color: "blue", row: 3},
{posX: 0, posY: 1, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 3},
{posX: 1, posY: 0, posZ: 1, color: "red", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 1, posZ: 1, color: "purple", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 0, posZ: 0, color: "black", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 1, posZ: 0, color: "blue", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 0, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 1, posZ: -1, color: "red", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 2, posZ: -1, color: "purple", row: 4},
{posX: 1, posY: 3, posZ: -1, color: "yellow", row: 4},
{posX: 2, posY: 0, posZ: 0, color: "green", row: 5},
{posX: 2, posY: 1, posZ: 0, color: "green", row: 5},
{posX: 2, posY: 2, posZ: 0, color: "yellow", row: 5}];

console.log(randomFloatingCube(cube_arr, -2, 2, -1, 2));
```